# Backbone.js fetch not actually setting attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a basic backbone model, its `urlRoot` attribute is set and the corresponding target on the server side returns a correct JSON output (both JSON string and `application/json` header).

I call a fetch like this:

```
var athlete = new Athlete({ id: 1 });
athlete.fetch();
```

at this point if I add a

```
console.log(athlete);
```

I can see the model, and inspecting it in firebug I can open the attributes object and see all the values returned from the server.

BUT if I do a:

```
console.log(athlete.get('name'));
```

I get `undefined` (the name appears under the attributes in the DOM inspection I mentioned above)

also doing a:

```
console.log(athlete.attributes);
```

returns an object containing only `{id: 1}` which is the argument I passed while creating the model.

If I create the model like this:

```
var athlete = new Athlete(<JSON string copypasted from the server response>);
```

then everything works fine, the `.get()` method returns whatever I ask, and `athlete.attributes` shows all the values.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`fetch` is asynchronous, which means that the data won't be available if you immediatly call `console.log(athlete.get('name'))` after the fetch.

Use events to be notified when the data is available, for example

```
var athlete = new Athlete({id: 1});
athlete.on("change", function (model) {
     console.log(model.get('name'));
});
athlete.fetch();
```

or add a callback to your fetch

```
var athlete = new Athlete({ id: 1 });
athlete.fetch({
    success: function (model) {
        console.log(model.get('name'));
    }
});
```

or take advantage of the promise returned by `fetch`:

```
athlete.fetch().then(function () {
    console.log(athlete.get('name'));
});
```

Comment: Of course now I realize how obvious it was, thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 1):

Just as a quick remark when using events in this example. It did not work with `change` in my case because this events fire on every change. So `sync` does 
the trick.

```
var athlete = new Athlete({id: 1});
athlete.on("sync", function (model) {
   console.log(model.get('name'));
});
athlete.fetch();
```