# fetch is not updating collection.model.models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection that i've initialized like this:

```
myCollection = new MyCollection([], {type: 'animals', params: {username: 'steve'}});

myCollection.fetch();

console.log(myCollection)  // prints out an object that includes 'models' and the newly fetched models

console.log(myCollection.models)  // prints out an empty list []
```

does anyone know why?

Comment: what does your collection function look like? Also, why are you passing in an empty array?

Comment: Probably an asynchronism problem. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584870/backbone-js-fetch-not-actually-setting-attributes/9585427#9585427

Comment: fetch is an asynchronous operation so whatever you do immediately after fetch is most likely executed before the fetch is finished, which leads to quite random results. put the console logging inside the `fetch`'s `success`-function and see what happens

Comment: Thanks @jakee putting it inside success worked - was an async problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetch is an asynchronous operation so whatever you do immediately after fetch is most likely executed before the fetch is finished, which leads to quite random results. put the console logging inside the fetch's success-function and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

The model of your collection must have an url to the server to fetch it into a collection, my thought that you have it on "MyCollection", just in case. And then you only need to add a success callback to display the collection populated, like this:

```
myCollection = new MyCollection([], {type: 'animals', params: {username: 'steve'}});

myCollection.fetch({
  success : function(returnedCollection, response){
       console.log(returnedCollection);  

        console.log(returnedCollection.models);
  }
});
```