# backbone.js fetch model + django

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js

i try create rest-api for django + backbone.js, and i have trouble, model.fetch() does not update the default model values. Where i made mistake?

backbone.js model

```
 window.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
     urlRoot: '/user/',
     initialize: function() {
    console.log("init Model User");
     }
     defaults: {
    name: "Default title",
    pass: 2011,
     }
 });
```

backbone.js view

```
window.UserView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize:function () {
        console.log('Initializing User View');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);

        this.model.fetch ({
             success: function () {
                 alert('success');
             }
        });
        console.log(this.model);

        this.render();
    },

    render:function () {
        console.log('Print tpl UserView');
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Create view

```
var userView = new UserView({model: new User()});
```

django response [{"name": "LOLOLO", "pass": "12345"}]

console.log(this.model)

print

```
attributes: Object
0: Object
name: "LOLOLO"
pass: "12345"
__proto__: Object
name: "Default title"
pass: 2011
```

Comment: have you tried to use the `reset` event instead of the `change` event? Does the model change at all? Sry but that print is useless if i have to recreate the order of appearance

Comment: yes, i try `reset`, but nothing happened

Comment: can you verify your model does change? just log it to the console inside of the success callback of fetch (The response of Django should be without the square brackets i guess)

Comment: Probably similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584870/backbone-js-fetch-not-actually-setting-attributes/9585427#9585427

Comment: try [stackoverflow.com/questions/9584870/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584870/backbone-js-fetch-not-actually-setting-attributes/9585427#9585427) return default value model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `console.log(this.model)` is right after the `fetch` call.

It's pretty probable that when you are logging the model, the response hasn't yet arrived from the server so you only get the default values.

Try putting the console.log call inside the success callback of fetch