# Backbone model doesn't fetch response instant but renders view first

Tags: backbone.js, model

I've model with a parse function

```
var File = Backbone.Model.extend({
   ...
   parse: function(response) {
      console.log('Parsing response')
   }
});

var FileView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  initialize: function(id) {
     this.file = new File({id: id.id});
     console.log('Fetching object')
     this.file.fetch();

     this.render();
   },

   render: function() {
      console.log('Rendering view');
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.file.JSON()));
   }
})
```

The expected result would be:

```
Fetching object
Parsing response 
Rendering view
```

But this is what I got:

```
Fetching object
Rendering view
Parsing response
```

Why is this? According to the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse%5C):

> parse is called by Backbone whenever a collection's models are
>   returned by the server, in fetch.

Why isn't the parse function called directly after fetching the model? How force it to do this?

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584870/backbone-js-fetch-not-actually-setting-attributes/9585427#9585427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, but you're making an async call to the server to fetch the model, so render is actually being called **before** you get answer. You have to do, something like this:

```
this.file.fetch({success: function () { 
    //call render here
}});
```

Comment: I cannot access `this.render()` inside the callback. `Cannot call method render() of undefined`

Comment: You have to do var that = this; somewhere before fetching, and than call that.render() in success function :)