# BackboneJS + Lodash _.union method

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, lodash

In my Backbone App i'm trying to merge collections by using the `_.union`-method from Lodash (Underscore).

So I have the following:

```
var myCollection = _.union([carsCollection], [motorcycleCollection], [bikeCollection]);
```

when I do `console.log(collection)` it gives me `[child, child, child]` where each `child` contains an array of the Models from the collection and its attributes. So far so good, my question is now:

How can I display this in a View? I tried:

```
this.insertView(new View({collection: myCollection }));
```

but that didnt work...

Does anyone know whta the issue is here?

Answer (score 1):

Backbone collections are not arrays of models, using  `_.union` on them won't produce a collection of models. You have to work with the `collection.models` and then build a new collection :

```
var models = _.union(
    carsCollection.models,
    motorcycleCollection.models,
    bikeCollection.models
);
var unitedCollection = new Backbone.Collection(models);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/uc5cn/ for a demo

Comment: Ok, I actually tried that, and it returns an empty collection. Even though I for example do `carsCollection.fetch()` before defining the `_.union`-method. Why is that?

Comment: Probably because your collections are empty when you use `_.union` : `fetch` is asynchronous and won't block, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584870/backbone-js-fetch-not-actually-setting-attributes/9585427#9585427 for example