# Backbone.js model from external JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm new to Backbone. Can you give me a hint what am I missing here?

here is my model:

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({

  url: 'json/item.json',

  parse: function(response){
    return response.item;
  },
});

var item = new Item();
item.fetch();
```

in console "item.toJSON();" shows the result as expected - id, title etc. But when item is passed through view to template

```
...
this.$el.append( template( item.toJSON() ) );
...
```

it can't pick any of the attributes - e.g. item.title -> undefined.

json file looks like this:

```
{
"item":{
    "title": "something something",
     .....
     }
}
```

Comment: You have to show your View definition

Comment: but I mean View works fine, I assume it has something to do with fetching? Because if I add:

    var newItem = item.toJSON():

in the console I will get an empty object:

    newItem
    Object {}

but then again from the console "item.toJSON();" shows the full object as it should be.

Comment: u'd better to attach full View code, but i think problem may be caused by mistake in this line: `this.$el.append( template( item.toJSON() ) );`   try to use `this.$el.append(_.template( template_html, item.toJSON() ) );`

Comment: @Evgeniy Since Underscore 1.7.0, Underscore templates no longer accept an initial data object. `_.template` always returns a function now.  See http://underscorejs.org/#changelog

Comment: @flawlessvictory Probably closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584870/backbone-js-fetch-not-actually-setting-attributes/9585427#9585427

Comment: @flawlessvictory And for the console showing the data http://stackoverflow.com/a/11463190/1071630

Comment: @nikoshr, many thanks, missed that

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
var item = new Item();
item.fetch();
```

This code is probably **not synchronous**, correct?

Therefore, the fetch has not finished yet when you immediately try to render it!

You can see the object in the console because it's already populated.

Your fetch probably should accept a callback or return a Promise in order to let you know when fetching is done.

```
var item = new Item();
item.fetch().then(function(fetchedItem){
  console.log(item === fetchedItem) // true
  this.$el.append( template( item.toJSON() ) );
}.bind(this));
```