# Backbone Marionette 3 app: Collection fetch returns empty array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

The problem I am having is that whenever I call listaCollection.toJSON() after calling listaCollection.fetch() it returns an empty array. If I do however console.log(data.toJSON()) in the success callback in the fetch method I will be able to see that it is correctly fetching it. If I am rather new to backbone/marionette so any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code.

```
import Bb from 'backbone';
import Mn from 'backbone.marionette';
import template from '../templates/ListasTemplate.jst';

const ListaCollection = Bb.Collection.extend({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/lista/all",
  parse(data) {
    return data.lista;
  }
});

const listaCollection = new ListaCollection();

listaCollection.on("change", function() {
  reset();
});

listaCollection.fetch({
  success(data) {
    console.log(data.toJSON());
  }
});

const ListasView = Mn.View.extend({
  collection: listaCollection,
  className: "mdl-grid",
  regions: {
    listasContainer: "#listas-container"
  },
  template: template
});

export default ListasView;
```

And this is my template:

```
<% _.each(items, function(item) { %>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
    <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text"><%= item.titulo %></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <%= item.descricao %>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect show-modal">
          <i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i>
        </button>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
        </button>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: You haven't shown in question where/how you're calling `.toJSON()`. You should wait the the fetch to complete. Pretty sure this is a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone.js fetch not actually setting attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584870/backbone-js-fetch-not-actually-setting-attributes)

Comment: @TJ Sorry. My bad. I was calling toJSON in the parse method inside the listaCollection factory declaration. But when I call data.toJSON() I get an error stating that toJSON is not a function (I imagine because the output already is JSON).

Comment: @TJ Sorry but would you mind in pointing out to me where the duplicate is?

Comment: @TJ Should I be resetting the view or something after I have fetched? I have updated the code in the question by the way.

Comment: @TJ I am aware that fetch is async but how do I inject the data in the View once it has loaded?

Comment: I guess what I am asking is. How do I get the data to render in the collection?

Comment: why(/what is) reset() on collection change?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and update the code exactly as the code that you are trying. There is no `toJSON` inside `parse` in the shared code.  It is not clear what is `reset `.  Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

> I was calling toJSON in the parse method inside the listaCollectionfactory declaration

Well, the return value of `parse` method is set as the data in collection. So if you call `toJSON` inside `parse`, data is not set yet, so it'll return empty array.